# Как отобразить прямоугольник из одного PictureBox в другом?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Всем привет, скажите, у меня есть 2 pictureBox'a в первом есть такая картинка:

[image]

А второй пустой, и при нажатии на первый выделяется невидимый прямоугольник 32х32, а всё, что попало в его радиус, можно будет перенести в pictureBox2, как такое сделать?

Comment: А как найти радиус прямоугольника?  
Прямоугольник 32х32

Comment: Ну я думал сделать через:

BitMap bitmap = new BitMap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

graphics.DrawRectangle(Pans.Blue,32,32,32,32);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Отследить клик мыши.
2. Выбрать прямоугольник по координатам в первом PictureBox.
3. Скопировать его содержимое в буфер.
4. Отобразить буфер во втором PictureBox.

Операции по копированию данных в или из PictureBox удобно делать с помощью [методов класса Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4cy2c290.aspx).